# Binding to Dataset Selected Row

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, dataset

Is there any way bind textboxes to the row of a dataset that is selected in a combobox?  For example I have a dataset with 2 columns, one called name (this is the primary key) and the other is called author.  I would like to set up databinding so that when the user selects the name in the combobox the corresponding author appears in the text of a textbox.

Specifically I want to know if this can be done through databinding or if it will require code for the selecteditemchanged event, or if it should be done using a value converter.

I think it would be possible to do with a value converter, but I was hoping it could be accomplished entirely in XAML.

This turned out to be a good tutorial to follow for building the appropriate code using the visual studio wizards for all the data stuff.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547149.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=comboboxName, Path=SelectedItem.author}" />
```

`comboboxName`is Name attribute of your ComboBox
`.author` is field name

Answer (score 0):

Yes you bind to ElementName and then for path SelecteItem.PropertyName.  Search MSDN on .NET Binding ElementName.